# Is this proof by contradiction that 9+13√3 is irrational correct?

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

[image: Irrationality proof]

If there is a fault in the logic, please explain it in simple terms.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the proof is fine. Typically, it is considered bad form on this website to link to other places, especially images of text, to give your question. It would have been better if you had copied it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no problem with the logic, you are assuming that $\sqrt 3$ is irrational. I don't think this is what you were intended to do, since showing that $\sqrt 3$ is irrational would be the most difficult step in the proof.